# Trimming carriage return (\r) in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, carriage-return

I have this simple piece of code here:

```
foreach my $key (keys %$structure)
{
    $key =~ s/\r?$//;
    $structure->{$key} =~ s/\r?$//;
}
```

This is a part of my trimming function, which takes in a reference to an object. This object (a hash, in our case) was previously initialized from the keyboard.

The problem is that each typed argument has an \r at the end, which is not very cool for outputting the structure. And even though I'm trying to substitute the \r with a regex, *it just won't work*. Why is that?

Comment: When you change the `$key` (first line) and then do `$structure->{$key}` then this changed key is _added to_ your structure.  So then you have both the old one, with `\r` and its value, and the new one, without `\r`.  Remedy shown in Ted's answer...

Comment: The new, added, key (without `\r`) doesn't have a value when you run a regex on it (second line in the loop); so there should be a warning (`Use of uninitialized value...`).  The fact you're not mentioning it tells me that you don't have `use warnings;` at the begging of the script?  You must always have that, and `use strict;`.  (But if you did get the warning then please always include that info in your question.)

Comment: ```%structure = map { chomp; $_ } %structure```

Comment: You should strip `\r` on input and forget about it in the code after that. There is a command to do it `chomp`. In case if you read a file from Windows (it is only system I know where present `\r`) then you have to remember to strip `\r` as in UNIX/Linux `chomp` strips only `\n` and you have to resort to something like `$line =~ s/\r\n//`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to use chomp the keyboard input and then use that value as a key rather than modify a key of a hash later on.
If you're using STDIN in the same script than save the STDIN to a variable and wrap that in a chomp.

```
       chomp($variable = <STDIN>);
```

Then use the variable as a key.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really is much easier

Answer (score 3):

You have a few syntactical errors and you also don't delete the old `$key`.

Something like this should work:

```
foreach my $key (keys %structure) {
    my $value =  $structure{$key};
    delete $structure{$key};
    $key =~ s/\r$//;
    $structure{$key} = $value;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
%structure = map { $a = $structure{$_}; s/\r$//; $_ => $a } keys %structure;
```

Comment: Another one-line variant, for giggles (assuming Perl 5.14+):
`$structure{ s/\r$//r } = delete $structure{$_} for keys %structure;`

Comment: @JimDavis Cool .. but they're trimming `\r` from the value as well and when it's all crammed into one statement it's harder (unwieldy) to fix for that....

Answer (score 3):

The chomp function answers your question

```
chomp $key
...
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-chomp-function/

Comment: This requires the input record separator to be `\r`. If that's not the case, `chomp` won't remove the `\r`.

Comment: I would tend to link the official documentation, https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp, rather than geeksforgeeks, as its description of the function is more complete (rather than 2 examples showing how it behaves).

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have stated `chomp` removes the trailing newline character. It also works on hashes, i.e., `chomp(%some_hash)` removes the newline character of every value of that hash. It does not change the keys.

***EDIT***:
It also chomps every element of an array. So you can do this:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'my %hey = ("a\n" => "b\n", "c\n" => "d"); 
                        chomp(my @a = %hey); %hey = (@a); print Dumper(\%hey)'
```

```
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => 'd',
          'a' => 'b'
        };
```

This might be resource intensive if the hash is large. And `"\r"` is not `chomp`ed on all systems. I recommend iterating over the hash and using `s`(or `chop` if every key and value ends with `"\r"`) as a better solution.

Comment: @TedLyngmo : I am not suggesting `chomp(%hash)` as a complete solution. I am just informing that `chomp` can act in different contexts too. `chomp(my @a = %h); %h = @a;` will work as a complete solution but wastes resources.